# htaccess prevent direct access to files while allowing rewrite rules to access them

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

### General Overview

I've been creating this really nice .htaccess file with a bunch of settings that work great so far. I am wondering if it is possible, now, to allow access to files through flat links only while denying access to the same files directly.

---

### Explanation & Current Settings

To better present this question consider the following:
I have a file: i.e. `myFile.php`
Which is in a subfolder: i.e. `my/path/to/file/`
The file's full path would then be `my/path/to/file/myFile.php`
Accessing this file through a URL, one would write: `my.domain.com/my/path/to/file/myFile.php`

In my .htaccess file, I have written a rewrite rule, similar to the following line of code (preceded by some `RewriteCond`'s that ensure conditions are met regarding the host and filenames respectively):

```
RewriteRule ^home$ \/my\/path\/to\/file\/myFile.php [NC,L]
```

This means that someone trying to get to my page `my/path/to/file/myFile.php` can simply write `my.domain.com/home` instead of the ugly path `my.domain.com/my/path/to/file/myFile.php`.

---

### Question & Preferred Outcome

What I am asking is:
Is it possible to block access to `myFile.php` if a person or machine attempts to go to `my.domain.com/my/path/to/file/myFile.php`, all the while allowing access to the file through `my.domain.com/home`?

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to block access to myFile.php if a person or machine attempts to go to `my.domain.com/my/path/to/file/myFile.php`, all the while allowing access to the file through `my.domain.com/home`

Yes it is possible using `THE_REQUEST` variable, represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

You can use this rule to block direct access to that particular file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /my/path/to/file/myFile\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: `//` was a typo in my answer (fixed) and you don't need to escape `/`

Comment: Thank you, changed my code and removed backslashes escaping slashes