# Blocking file from being accessed directly but still allowed in rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a file on my server called /files.php

I don't access it directly, instead I use .htaccess and pass parameters to it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/robots\.txt(\?.*)?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /files.php?file=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I'd like to prevent people from accessing this file directly but still allow my server to use it in rewrite rules. Ideally I'd like to give a 404 error if the user tries to access it directly. I came up with this:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/files\.php
```

Unfortunatly that line also prevent my rewrite rule from working too.

Comment: If your environment allows it, you could move your files.php outside your DOCUMENT_ROOT (so it's not accessible directly) and still map the request to it, see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside

Comment: Unfortunately that won't be possible for me. The whole reason I even have files.php is because I needed something inside the document root. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130524/sharing-htaccess-file-and-resources-between-domains

Comment: And do you have to do this through .htaccess? another trick is to define a constant on your initial index.php (or some other bootstrapping .php file that you always load) and check for the existence of that constant in files.php. If it's not defined, you `die()`it.

Comment: Or, take I look at this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36943984/1227446

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the top of your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /file\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

This will return a 404 error if /file.php is direct accessed.

%{THE_REQUEST} is important to avoid rewrite loop error or rule's overriding.